# Vb string replacement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, replace

```
Dim sr as new IO.streamreader(xxx.txt)
Dim sw as new IO.streamwriter(xxxx.txt)
Dim s as string = sr.readtoend
dim ssss as string
dim i as integer
while not sr.endofstream
    for i = 0 to 10
        ssss = "hello" & listbox.items(i)
        s = replace(s,"[[abc]]",ssss)
       Call sw.writeline(s)
    Next
End while
call sw.close()
```

I was trying to replace the string [[abc]] in a .txt file called xxx with ssss and then write it into another .txt named xxxx. The problem is that ssss is changing all the time  and when I debug the program it says s is "Nothing". I need all ssss values in the new txt. So I wonder maybe "Replace" is not suitable in this case? Any ideas on how to fix this issue? BTW, I am using vb in vs 2012, not vb 6.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are having errors with null. Try to catch whenever "s" is nothing, then if it is, skip it. Otherwise do the Replace.

Check it with something like

```
         if s <> nothing then
             s = s.replace(s,"[[abc]]",ssss)
            Call sw.writeline(s)
         next
```

Comment: You are right. when i>0, there'll be no [[abc]] anymore since it's been replaced already while i =0. if I do what you recommended, then I may get only one "ssss" or "s", but I need all ssss when i = 0 to 10. e.g. When i =0, ssss = "hello" & listbox.items(0); when i = 1, ssss= "hello" & listbox.items(1),etc, and then substitute all ssss in to [[abc]] line by line. However, I still don't know how to make this approach T_T

Comment: It seems to me.. that the loop is redundant? Try removing the FOR control structure, since it seems for each line of text in a notepad file you loop 10 times to do a replace.

Comment: The for loop is necessary because there are 11 items in the listbox.My goal is to print out each one of them and then substitute them ALL in the .txt file at the same time. Probably I should put s somewhere else  out of the loop since ssss is the only thing needed to be looped